# Can I connect low-power resistors to achieve a high-power resistive load?

Tags: resistors, switch-mode-power-supply, resistance, load, test-equipment

I've designed an 80 W 400 V PFC boost converter and I want to test it with resistive load. but I couldn't find a low-cost high power (20 to 80 watts) resistor in the range of 2k to 10k ohm. Is there any problem connecting for example 80 individual 1W simple axial film resistors in series and parallel to result in the desired resistance and power rating?

Comment: Just be mindful of the voltage across resistors. I'm not sure of the spec for 1 W resistors, but I seem to recall about 200 V limit across much smaller resistors.

Comment: +1 on @jonk You are only limited by the voltage rating. If that’s no issue then parallel away.

Comment: An aside: Designing such a PFC already cost a lot in your time, and will cost more in EMC testing etc. I really suggest doing the "time engineering" here: look at how much time you'll spend dealing with "cheaper" resistors. Account for all of it - putting together the load, designing a PCB for the load, etc. Multiply the time by your gross hourly rate - the real cost to your employer. Then compare to "expensive" resistor cost. I bet you the "expensive" resistor is really cheap once you do the math.

Comment: @winny well I think the voltage rating would be satisfied when I connect for example 10 resistors in series and 3 parallel columns (30pcs overall). right?

Comment: Yes, much better.